# Are there any tools that can be used to check for IE compatibility?

Tags: internet-explorer

Are there any tools that can be used to check for IE compatibility, and list the incompatible items?

Comment: Well yes: MS IE is a good tool for that. Load the page and check for problems/errors.

Comment: If you don't mind about the <5% who use IE7-, just test in IE8, and then in the real browsers like Chrome, FF etc... [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on Linux and Mac is convenient to test IE8. Works very well. There are some tools to emulate or to run simultaneously several IEs, but it's not up to professional standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  http://www.modern.ie/

Recently created by Microsoft and highlights some of the trickier things to test (compatibility mode etc.)